# Запятая при перечислении: "Ученику нашей школы, Герою Советского Союза(,) старшему сержанту..."

Tags: запятые, приложение, однородные-неоднородные-определения

В предложении нужна ли запятая :

> ...посвященной ученику нашей школы, Герою Советского Союза(,) старшему сержанту Шолыгину С.А.

После "Союза" нужна ли запятая? Я думаю, что да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы не поставила, потому что здесь приложения неоднородные, характеризуют человека с разных сторон - указывают армейское звание и звание-награду.

Я бы и перед "Герою" не поставила, но тогда получится громоздкая конструкция, лучше поставить как уточнение

Comment: Тогда если уточнение, то и после Союза запятая? Что уточняем?

Comment:  ...,посвященной ученику нашей школы,Герою Советского Союза  старшему сержанту Шолыгину С.А,... Ученику нашей школы (кому именно?)

Comment: Спасибо. Все теперь ясно.

Answer (score 2):

Военные звания, стоящие непосредственно перед фамилией, не являются однородными по отношению
к предшествующим приложениям. Например: дважды Герой Советского Союза капитан 2-го ранга Леонов. 
В первом приложении запятая нужна, т.к оно не стоит непосредственно перед фамилией. 
***Былинский, Розенталь. Трудные случаи пунктуации.***