# Обязательно ли добавлять "бывший"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Обязательно ли добавлять "бывший", когда мы говорим о бывших учениках, студентах, работниках и т. п.?

Например, в вопросе [Запятая при перечислении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47995/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8) не следовало бы написать "посвящённый *бывшему* ученику нашей школы"? А еще лучше - "посвящённый выпускнику нашей школы"

По-моему, нужно различать три ситуации: речь идет о мальчике, погибшем будучи учеником; речь идет о человеке, который окончил эту школу; речь идет о человеке, который когда-то был учеником этой школы, но не окончил ее.

Хотелось бы узнать мнение наших экспертов о каждой из них.

Дополнение.

Бывших президентов США продолжают называть президентами всю жизнь. Но этому есть свое объяснение. В Америке президент — не только должность, но и звание, а звание это — на всю жизнь. В отличие от американских президентов, российский (советский) школьник ("ученик нашей школы") — это только "должность". По-моему, "стенд, посвященный ученику нашей школы Иванову" звучит корректно, только в трех случаях:

- Иванов является учеником нашей школы в данный момент;
- Иванов погиб, будучи учеником нашей школы;
- стенд посвящен тем годам, когда Иванов был учеником нашей школы (а он сам жив поныне или ушел в мир иной в зрелом возрасте).

Может я излишне формален, но во всех остальных случаях не нахожу оправдания тому, что взрослого человека (даже погибшего как герой) называют "учеником нашей школы".

Comment: А с чего вы вообще взяли, что этот мальчик-герой погиб? Может это какой стенд, посвященный вполне себе живому человеку. Как "парта Ельцина".

Comment: @Мимоходов , Если мальчик не погиб, то это второй или третий случай.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетание "**ученик нашей школы**" (если оставить в стороне редкий случай упоминания о навеки оставшемся учеником) имеет сильный оттенок *текущего времени*: первая реакция - это об "*учащемся*" (ныне или в момент, о котором повествуют). Такого не происходит с понятиями "**выпускник**" или "**учившийся в нашей школе**", внутренне выражающих значение "бывший" (ученик). Не требует уточнения "бывший" и упоминание об "*однокласснике*" кого-то давно закончившего школу - слово не связано с "учебным" процессом и отражает лишь связи людей. Если речь идёт не о выпускнике (по какой-либо причине человек не закончил эту школу), проще всего назвать человека "*учившимся в нашей школе*". Это позволит обойтись без добавления слова "бывший", которое больше подходит к "ученику", не так давно перешедшему в другую школу. "Бывшим учеником" (вместо комплиментарного "выпускник") могут назвать и в родной школе закончившего её преступника, пытаясь этим наименованием от его дел отмежеваться.

**P.S.** Особые случаи, когда "нет бывших":

1. Случаи, по смыслу не требующие оговорок (однократно обретаемый статус): *космонавт*, (вынужден извиниться за последующие элементы ряда) у*бийца, клятвопреступник, людоед...*
2. Традиции исторического почитания, формально требующие уточнения: *такой-то по счёту президент США* (или "президент + фамилия"), *такой-то по счёту чемпион мира по шахматам* (их ещё меньше), *олимпийский чемпион* (такого-то города проведения Игр)...

Answer (score 0):

Это стилистика, вещь субъктивная и потому не мой конек, но попробую, вопрос интересный.

> А еще лучше - "посвящённый выпускнику нашей школы"

Да, это лучше всего, но тут говорить-то не о чем. Разве что придраться к значению слова "выпускник".

Вот со словом "бывший" действительно интересно.

> не следовало бы написать "посвящённый бывшему ученику нашей школы"?

Здесь - нет. Тут все от контекста зависит. Попробую порассуждать конкретно на том примере, ибо абстрактно что-то не получается. 
С одной стороны без "бывшей" может возникнуть ощущение, что речь идет об ученике, ставшем героем в бытность свою учеником. Правда если это Герой СССР это менее вероятно... 
С другой стороны "бывший" производит ощущение, что человек в этой школе не доучился до выпуска.

Может сказаться даже то, о чем вообще речь идет: если о какой-то мемориальной доске (героя уже нет в живых), то "бывший" даже как-то некрасиво смотрится на фоне увековечения памяти.

В общем, тут должно срабатывать языковое чутье в учетом всего словесного контекста и ситуации вообще. По одному обрубку фразы и не скажешь наверняка.
Но в целом, "бывший" тут скорее будет чем-то инородным, чем необходимым. Во всех трех условных случаях.